# Always Show Tooltip ( Angular Material2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have somebuttons

```
            <button mdTooltip="bye" mdTooltipPosition="left" md-mini-fab>
                BYE
            </button>
            <button mdTooltip="hi" mdTooltipPosition="left" md-mini-fab>
                HI
            </button>
```

The tooltips show on "hover" by default. Is there a way to make it always show? (Show on page load and stay)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add imports:

```
import {MdTooltip} from '@angular/material';
```

then add reference names to tooltips:

```
<div>
  <button #tooltipBye="mdTooltip" 
          mdTooltip="bye" 
          mdTooltipPosition="below" 
          md-mini-fab>
          BYE
  </button>
  <button #tooltipHi="mdTooltip"
          mdTooltip="hi" 
          mdTooltipPosition="below" 
          mdTooltipHideDelay="1000" 
          md-mini-fab>
          HI
    </button>
</div>
```

Pass references of these elements in the component. Then use `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook to call the `show()` method.

component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('tooltipHi') tooltipHi: MdTooltip;
@ViewChild('tooltipBye') tooltipBye: MdTooltip;

ngAfterViewChecked(){

  if(this.tooltipHi._isTooltipVisible() == false){
    this.tooltipHi.show();
  }
  if(this.tooltipBye._isTooltipVisible() == false){
    this.tooltipBye.show();
  }

}
```

Here's the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JP0mCkCCAdbayf7B7cT9?p=preview)

Comment: Is there a way to group these buttons and use one selector and one show() for all of them?

Comment: As far as I know, material doesn't have a button group, also each tooltip is different, since the messages in them are different also. So, I don't think/know of any way to combine them to use only one selector :(