# How to make MatTooltip to be visible on focus instead of hover?

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

Is there a way in which I can set the tooltip to be visible on focus instead of upon hovering?

I've tried to understand from angular official documentation and search similar question on SO including this one [Always Show Tooltip ( Angular Material2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959479/always-show-tooltip-angular-material2), but I don't see something helpful so far.

My code is:

```
<input
  matTooltipPosition="above"
  matTooltipClass="my-tooltip"
  matTooltip='Fill in the field and then click "Enter"'
  (focus)="tooltip.show()"
  #tooltip="matTooltip">
```

I also tried `TooltipVisibility = "Visible"` with no success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always Show Tooltip ( Angular Material2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959479/always-show-tooltip-angular-material2)

Comment: That didn't work for me, tried it.

Comment: @ddy250 Show the code that you have tried!

Comment: I've added it in the edit but don't think it can help in any way.

Comment: The point of the tooltip is to be shown and hidden. If you want something that looks like a tooltip and always shown then make a new div with the tooltip content and put it next to the input.Or please explain your point

Comment: @Vega I want it to be shown/hidden, but instead of on hover I want it to be on focus - meaning when I click the input field rather then hovering it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tooltip will disappear if a focus event is fired.

You may have two workarounds:

a. Put the tooltip on a hidden element, i.e. a div, and make it appear on the input focus. But the input should not have any tooltip:

HTML:

```html
<input (focus)="tooltip.show()">
<div class="hiddenTooltip"
     matTooltipPosition="below"
     matTooltipClass="my-tooltip"
     matTooltip='Fill in the field and then click "Enter"'
     #tooltip="matTooltip">
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.hiddenTooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 3em
}
```

---

b. Make a fake tooltip that you show/hide with ngIf:

HTML

```html
<input (focus)="show=true" (blur)="show=false">
<div #tooltip *ngIf="show" class="fakeTooltip">
  Fill in the field and then click "Enter"
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.fakeTooltip {
  background: rgb(65, 64, 64);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.75em;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yhwt6x)

Comment: That worked, thanks. How come in this case there is no need to hover over the div in order for the tooltip to appear? The .show() method overcomes that?

Comment: I guess it's for the first example? Then yes. The div is hidden, so there is no hover event on it and its tooltip stays hidden also, until input focus would fire it with show()

Answer (score 3):

The advice my friend gave me saved me a lot of time: Just add a matTooltipHideDelay. This way the tooltip stays visible and you can easily inspect it.

```
matTooltipHideDelay="1000000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a tooltip is your best option here. It's hard to tell exactly what you want without seeing your existing code.

---

If you're using the Angular Material form field component, you can use the hint label for your message instead of a tooltip. This keeps the message always visible and associated with the form field as the component automatically uses aria-describedby attribute to link the hint to the input. That's a great A11Y win.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter some input</mat-label>
    <input matInput #input maxlength="10">
    <mat-hint>Fill in the field and then click "Enter"</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

You could also use a suffix to insert an icon button with the tooltip. The user can tab to the button to focus it, which will display the tooltip. And you can add a toggle to the button so the user can show/hide the tooltip with the keyboard, mouse click, or touch event.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter some input</mat-label>
  <input matInput #input maxlength="10" />
  <button
    #tooltip="matTooltip"
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); tooltip.toggle()"
    mat-icon-button
    matSuffix
    matTooltip="Fill in the field and then click "Enter""
  >
    <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```